# JSON convert takes time

Tags: c#, json.net

[image]

I have 1244 records like this and It takes more than a minute to convert to json. this is kind of unacceptable for my project.

am I doing something wrong? How do I optimize this?

**CODE**

```
    string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
```

**Object Type**

```
 {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Foo.Entity.MoreFoo,<>f__AnonymousTypee<string,string,string,string,string,string,string>>}
```

Comment: Can you add some code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: I added Converting part and type, let me know If you need something else. thank you

Comment: Tracing? I fail to see what should take more than a minute on something like this. I suggest grabbing a profiler and using it.